# Cannot get Plots from ggplot in Rstudio

Tags: r, ggplot2, rstudio

I'm new to R. I have been working on plotting data, which was working fine, but all of a sudden I'm simply not getting any plot in Rstudio. I've reinstalled Rstudio. Am I missing something in the code? Thanks

```
    library(ggplot2)
    library(Rmisc)
    SRL<-summarySE(CombinedwinrhizoSigmaPlot, measurevar="SLR", groupvars=c("Rootstock"))
    offset.v = -3
    offest.h = 0.5
    ggplot(SRL,aes(x=Roostock, y=SRL, ymax=70000, ymin = 0)) +
    geom_bar(stat="idendity",fill="gray50", colour="black", width = 0.7) +
    geom_errorbar(aes(ymax=SRL+se, ymin=SRL-se), width = 0.0, size=0.5, color = "black")+
    geom_text(aes(label=c("BC","BC","A","CDE","G","FG","EFG","CD","DEFG","CDEFG","AB","A","CD","CDEF","DEFG","CD","A","CDEFG"), hjust=offest.h, vjust=offest.v) +
   labs(x = "Rootstock", y = "Specific Root Length") + theme_bw() +
    theme(panel.grid.major.x = element_blank(),
    panel.grid.major.y = element_line(colour = "grey80"),
    plot.title = element_text(size = rel(1.5),
    face = "bold", vjust = 1.5),
    axis.title = element_text(face = "bold"),
    axis.title.y = element_text(vjust=1.8),
    axis.title.x = element_text(vjust= -0.5),
    panel.border = element_rect(colour="black")
   )
```

Since I cannot attach the .csv file, here is the dataset for CombinedwinrhizoSigmaPlot, it is only partial since it is quite large and I cannot attach it. The    geom_text will obviously not be correct since the number of Rootstock is less in this sample dataset than in the total set. Thank you!

```
    Rootstock   SLR
    A   33739.58824
    A   29812.64286
    A   29209
    A   31410.58824
    A   31833.39474
    A   18747.52381
    A   38536.79412
    A   25384.61702
    A   30997.22835
    A   17498.90625
    A   24195.32258
    A   23230.88158
    A   41197.3
    A   49207.17391
    A   49459.625
    A   48379.08333
    A   39909.5
    A   34406.26316
    A   34062.32
    A   41217.35417
    A   37801.85333
    A   32362.85235
    A   29592.44144
    A   41183.56311
    B   30143.42857
    B   36234.45455
    B   20233.33333
    B   37056
    B   28529.67568
    B   34542.05263
    B   37576.95238
    B   34754.15625
    B   20086.33333
    B   29096.5
    B   25690.225
    B   21062.61832
    B   38229.04167
    B   31150.44
    B   42008.95652
    B   40174.88571
    B   39374.97059
    B   34751.96296
    B   44326.18333
    B   35507.5283
    B   36021.58242
    B   40078.10744
    B   34904.34667
    B   34403.11594
    C   33633.44444
    C   30306
    C   44506
    C   24916.11111
    C   45506.75
    C   30893.53333
    C   63469.6
    C   29932.19231
    C   33791.26563
    C   21850.45714
    C   24615.34328
    C   29308.10484
    C   50217
    C   55341.42857
    C   54483.71429
    C   51372.22222
    C   50002.14286
    C   43051.16667
    C   49146.46667
    C   48473.44231
    C   32102.69298
    C   35886.97647
    C   34507.8
    C   45671.38636
```

Comment: It would be great if you could supply a minimal reproducible example to go along with your question. Something we can work from and use to show you how it might be possible to answer your question. That way others can also befit form your question, and the accompanying answer, in the future.  You can have a look at [this SO post](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) on how to make a great reproducible example in R. fx. what is `CombinedwinrhizoSigmaPlot`

Comment: What are the error messages you are getting? Btw, there are some typos in your code. `Roostock` instead of `Rootstock` and `idendity` instead of `identity`.

Comment: I'm not getting any error messages. No error messages and no plot.

Comment: and you have another typo in your ggplot() expression y=SRL vs SLR

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this will work. Thanks also to @Teja for picking up a few typos.

there was a few other typos in your code, be careful next time. I also calculated your upper and lower bars prior to running your plot (seems the way to go with ggplot2 v2). I did not include your geom_text() expression because some of the text was missing, but this code should fix your problem.

```
SRL$Lower <- SRL$SLR - SRL$se
SRL$Upper <- SRL$SLR + SRL$se

ggplot(SRL,aes(x=Rootstock, y=SLR)) +
    geom_bar(stat="identity",fill="gray50", colour="black", width = 0.7) + geom_errorbar(aes(ymax=Upper, ymin=Lower), size=0.5, color = "black") +    labs(x = "Rootstock", y = "Specific Root Length") + theme_bw() +
    theme(panel.grid.major.x = element_blank(),
          panel.grid.major.y = element_line(colour = "grey80"),
          plot.title = element_text(size = rel(1.5),
                                    face = "bold", vjust = 1.5),
          axis.title = element_text(face = "bold"),
          axis.title.y = element_text(vjust=1.8),
          axis.title.x = element_text(vjust= -0.5),
          panel.border = element_rect(colour="black")
    )
```

this give
[image]

Comment: Thank you! I found one missing parenthesis as well. All cleared up.

Comment: have you tried in the regular R console, not R studio?